# Timing rotations in OpenGL

Tags: opengl, timer

I am working my way through OpenGL Superbible 5th ed. There is sample code which displays a rotating torus on the screen. To ensure the rotation happens independent of processor speed, the rotation amount is based on time. My question: In the sample code below, how can I be "certain" that the correct time will be passed to the `m3dRotationMatrix44()`  method? That is, after `rotTimer.GetElapsedSeconds()`, what prevents the OS from working on other tasks, and then returning to `m3dRotationMatrix44()`? Or, is this an elementary timing technique for tutorial purposes? if that's the case, what other methods exist?

```
// Set up time based animation
static CStopWatch rotTimer;
float yRot = rotTimer.GetElapsedSeconds() * 60.0f;

// <initialize some stuff>

// Create a rotation matrix based on the current value of yRot
m3dRotationMatrix44(mRotate, m3dDegToRad(yRot), 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just put the timer query as close to where you're using it as possible, and then don't worry too much about it.  Note that at 60 Hz, you're only drawing a frame every 16 milliseconds anyways, so the granularity of your step is at least that much.  On a machine that's running mostly this application (and not loaded by other processes), the context switching time won't make significant difference.

If you think about it, there's not really anything that your userspace application *should* be able to do to guarantee that your execution won't be interrupted by another process.  Context switching is handled by the kernel, and for fairness, no userspace process should be able to "hog" all the execution time -- context switching should be entirely transparent to it.

Comment: So it's a matter of trust still? There's no mechanism that "guarantees" it? I'm not worried, just curious.

Comment: @robert.ecot: essentially yes.  If you want precise animations, you can get into more complicated schemes with estimating frame latency, but that seems like overkill for your application.

Answer (score 1):

If everything done right, you do not need to warry about OS doing something between rotTimer.GetElapsedSeconds() and calculations. "rotTimer.GetElapsedSeconds()" will return the cummulative delay spent on your stuff and other tasks. But you must use the same value for all your time-based operations ( call .GetElapsedSeconds() only once per frame and use it's value everywhere) on each frame.

What you should warry about is that the delay can be too big or too small. There are several approaches to tackle the problem. The most simple is to setup maximum frame length. Something like this:

```
float yRot = max(rotTimer.GetElapsedSeconds(), 0.3f) * 60.0f;
```

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing that prevents other processes from running while your program is running by default. Don't do this, but you can change your process priority to preempt any other process on the computer if you really need to using windows API functions SetPriorityClass and SetThreadPriority. Setting these to realtime is a good way to kill your computer. :-)